# How to protect against mistakenly removal of my aws ressources?

Tags: amazon-web-services

What if I delete by mistake my aws API or any other aws ressource that took several weeks/months to build ? Or if a malicious developer get fraudulent acces to my AWS and decide to delete all my hard work ?

Is there a kind of backup AWS make automatically to prevent against these scenarios ?

Comment: No. You need to prevent this by not allowing it. Write IAM policies that do not allow some destructive operations. Do code reviews to prevent accidental destruction. Preventing against a rogue employee is very difficult while keeping the normal developer still able to do their work. But even then you can implement that pull requests might need 3 approvers before being rolled out, etc. Overall this is completely unrelated to AWS and are just very general software / infrastructure development best practices. The exact same things would be relevant when deploying on GCP or even your own server.

Comment: If you build your infrastructure by hand by creating resources in the aws console and are actually relying on that resources being there then you are doing something wrong in the first place and should look into IaC.

Comment: FYI, IaC = Infrastructure as Code. This is the practice of deploying infrastructure via services like CloudFormation, which uses templates to define infrastructure. This allows the infrastructure to be re-created again in future if desired. It does _not_ include "backups", because it is best-practice that any code and configuration on instances should always be deployed from a source code repository (eg Git) so that it can be tracked, versioned and redeployed. You can also create AMIs and Snapshots of EC2 instances (see [AWS Backup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/).

Answer (score 1):

The way you have asked this question it is difficult to answer. If you could provide a specific scenario, we might be able to better assist. Here are my tips though:

1. You need to secure your environment with least privileges. Only turn on policies, access, process, etc, that you are using.
2. Turn on Monitoring with Cloud Watch so you can properly monitor your servers.
3. Turn on two factor Authentication for your IAM Account. Do not do this for Root. Only use Root to fix any two factor authentication issues.
4. Use Snapshots, AMIs, etc.
5. Use Versioning software for all of your code. Put your Lamda, Policies, and any other code or scripts you write in GIT so you don't loose them.

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

There is no blanket mechanism for backing up all resources in AWS for this scenario. You need to think of these scenarios and deploy infrastructure accordingly.
Unfortunately this topic is too wide to discuss in one comment.

You can think of preventing these accidental deletions by using IAM's and SCP's.

There are some services like AWS Backup which can help you with getting backups of your persistent data resources.
Refer: https://aws.amazon.com/backup/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc